# SAS input tables character columns format

Tags: sas

I have a set of tables in a SAS library that I have to compile but the width of some columns aren't the same. The tables have similar pattern names like "***BILLINGS_YYMM***".

```
DATA BILLINGS;
    SET BILLINGS_:;
RUN;
```

I have the following message in the log :

> WARNING: Several lengths have been specified for the variable
> PROCEDURE by the input SAS table(s). Risk of truncation of the data.

Is there a way to solve that without going through all the tables.

Comment: You should also watch out whether the variable(s) has any FORMAT attached to them.  If you end up with a variable that can store 100 bytes but has the `$20.` format attached to it then your print-outs will only show the first 20 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data billings ;
  length PROCUDURE $100. ; /* adjust $100 to reflect the longest across all datasets */
  set BILLINGS_: ;
run ;
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but it didn't work for all the variables. I was wondering if a similar width setup existed in SAS for character variable like BEST. for the numeric ones.

Comment: Do you have any examples of values it didn't work? Because increasing $100. to bigger value should work. For searching for the longest value (so you could put that number into length declaration) you can create table from dictionary.columns where libname="yourlib", and then search it for the largest length among your tables for that variable.

Comment: Thank you @Negdo, it works. I just didn't think about that. The issue was that the lenth in some of the tables weren't the same and that's why I had the warning message.